# Unable to connect to foreign data source: connect() failed: Connection refused [1]

Tags: cassandra, mariadb, datastax-enterprise

I'm following this [link](https://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2013/sites/default/files/slides/mysqlconf2013-mariadb-cassandra-interoperability.pdf) to implement MariaDB Cassandra interoperability. I have installed mariadb and cassandra on Ubuntu 14.04 and it's running. Also I have created mariadb keyspace in cassandra. When I tried to create table in mariadb, I get the following error:

```
MariaDB [test]> set global cassandra_default_thrift_host='127.0.0.1';Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> create table t2 (pk varchar(36) primary key, data1 varchar(60), data2 bigint ) engine=cassandra keyspace='mariadbtest' thrift_host='127.0.0.1' column_family='cfl';
ERROR 1429 (HY000): Unable to connect to foreign data source: connect() failed: Connection refused [1]
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `start_rpc: false` to `start_rpc : true` in cassandra.yaml file